# How does Angular's $q differ from the Promises/A+ spec?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

When writing a test, I recently got stung by Angular $q's behavior around throwing exceptions in `then` blocks: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz8f7tvs/))

```
 const r = $q.reject(new Error());
 r.then(null, () => {
   throw new Error();
 }).then(null, () => {
   // This does not get run!
   // Instead, an exception is thrown on the event loop somewhere
 });
```

I had assumed that $q adhered to Promises/A+, but it looks like that's not the case. ([Promises/A+ 2.2.7.2](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-42))

What other differences are there between $q and Promises/A+?

Comment: Nate_Rook. certainly looks like the final error handler should run. Can you provide a demo of it not working?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - Sure, I just fixed the jsfiddle link. (I got confused by the 'save local draft' functionality on jsfiddle :( )

Comment: @charlietfl that certainly doesn't appear to be the case here

Comment: Possibly related ~ https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3174

Comment: @Phil - Yep, looks like that's it. See http://jsfiddle.net/w7onz1gm/2/ --- if we're not in a test, we see the expected behavior. This is a test-only bug.

Comment: @NateRook, as it seems to be key, you might edit the question to indicate that the code is executed in a test, and add the "jasmine" tag.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Good call. It looks like the culprit is angular-mocks, not jasmine, and there's no tag for that, so I just mentioned in the question the relevant context: it's in a test.

Comment: You're asking volunteers to go through all of the `$q` code to find where it differs from Promises/A+?

Comment: This sounds like a bug you should report to the Angular team, not an intended deviation from the spec.

Comment: "It looks like the culprit is angular-mocks" ... that's worrying given that angular-mocks and `$q` come from the same stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular $q is Promises/A+ compliant; the Promises/A+ compliance tests are run as part of Angular's continuous build.

The behavior I described in the question is a [misfeature](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3174#issuecomment-250259596). Promises/A+ doesn't technically describe the behavior of `$exceptionHandler`, so it doesn't break compliance, but it does make these cases impossible to test. The Angular team plans to remove it in [1.6](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/15213).

Thanks to @Phil for pointing me in the right direction.